# Change the hiera 5 environment layer hiera.yaml location

Tags: puppet, hiera

**Background**
I am using `puppet5` & `hiera5` on a `puppet` master from separate `git` repos.
The code is deployed using `r10k` into their respective locations using the branch to environment directory mapping.
Due to the environment conflict limitation in `r10k` (apologies if this is no longer the case) I use a separate location for my `hieradata`:

`Puppet code - /etc/puppetlabs/code/envirnments/`
`Hiera code - /etc/puppetlabs/code/hieradata/`

I have a global `hiera.yaml` file in `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml` and an environment specific `hiera.yaml` file in my `hiera` branch / environment location.

e.g. `/etc/puppetlabs/code/hieradata/production/hiera.yaml`

**Problem**
My environment `hiera.yaml` is ignored due to its location, it is expected to be where my puppet `<ENVIRONMENT>` code is:

`/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hiera.yaml`

taken from https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/5.0/hiera_config_yaml_5.html#location

but instead it is:

`/etc/puppetlabs/code/hieradata/production/hiera.yaml`

**Solution**
The only solution that I have been able to find is to locate a `hiera.yaml` in my puppet code repo with a datadir set to

`datadir: ../../hieradata/%{::environment}/hieradata`
(it must be relative)

Which works ok but is not ideal so I am looking for other solutions.

Even if I set the global `hiera.yaml datadir` to:

`/etc/puppetlabs/code/hieradata/%{::environment}/`
(it can be a full path)

and do not have a `hiera.yaml` file in my puppet repo, `hiera` works, but the environmental `hiera.yaml` located there is ignored.

Another idea was to swap the locations but then my puppet code does not work.

So ideally what I need to do is set the environment layer `hier.yaml` location as it seems to be hard coded to `<ENVIRONMENT>`, which is where my puppet code is.

I still want to use `r10k` and I want to host my environmental `hiera.yaml` in my hiera repo.

Comment: The easiest solution would be a symlink from the hiera config deployed by r10k to the location Puppet expects it to be. Does that sound ok?

Comment: While that would work, it would get quite complicated due to the environments being linked to git branches, so if I was going to write something for that then I guess I would just not use r10k and script the whole lot.

Comment: Ok, then why not deploy your hiera config with your control repo and your hieradata as a module, both with r10k? You seem to already be halfway there, and that is normal use case these days.

Comment: I'm liking that idea @MattSchuchard I will investigate further! Cheers!

Comment: People have been asking for intrinsic hiera support for r10k for a while and it has not happened, but it might be in code manager (I haven't used code manager in a few months so I forget). Basically in the `Puppetfile` you have an entry for the hieradata and then use a `modulepath` key-value pair for that entry to install it in your custom hieradata directory. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

my working code:

```
datadir: "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/%{environment}/hiera"
```

but path should be correct.

Comment: Yes that is the default place for it, Is your hiera code in a different repo to your puppet code and are you using r10k?

Comment: yeap, im use r10k but use alone repo with different branch

Comment: Unfortunately the issue I am seeing is because they are in two different repos.

Comment: but r10k making for using 1 control repo + branches and can't work with multi repo - https://docs.puppet.com/pe/latest/cmgmt_control_repo.html

Possible work with 1 control repo + branches or make same tool because r10k have very simple logic